# cannot insert backslash with bash, python, works fine with csh, idle

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, command-line, bash, special-characters

I have a strange problem with inserting backslashes (Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04,
the upgrade changed nothing).
The key combination on my keyboard (Swedish Thinkpad T400) is AltGr + ?.
However, this seems not to be the problem, as it only appears with some
programs.

With for instance bash 4.2, python 2.7, python 3.2, swipl 5.10
I cannot type nor copy-paste backslash into the terminal. 
With ash, csh, ghci, nano, vi, idle, idle3 everything behaves as 
expected, I can both type and copy-paste. For instance, copying

```
echo gurka\\\\agurk
```

(four literal backslashes) and pasting it into csh (and then hitting enter), I get

```
$ csh
% echo gurka\\\\agurk
gurka\\agurk
```

but with bash, I get

```
$ echo gurkaagurk
gurkaagurk
```

Unfortunately, I noticed first quite a while after many new installations and I
can't tell when it first appeared.
I suspect a bug or conflicting configuration of some library common
to the first group but not to the second, but I am unsure on how to go on.
It is extremely annoying and I am grateful for hints.

UPDATE: the behaviour is the same for konsole and whatever you get with 
Ctrl-Alt-F1 (which is what I had tested). It also does not work with gnome-terminal and xterm, but these two indicate error (by flashing). Ideas about what to check?

UPDATE: Problem is solved, thanks to Gilles! It was a misconfiguration of the readline library (.inputrc)

Marcus

Comment: What terminal are you using?  May help to identify where the problem is.

Comment: I have here hardy+lucid+natty and all do this echo gurka\\\\agurk shows
gurka\\agurk

Comment: How do you do copy/paste?  Did you use right-click and paste (in GUI)?  I suspect you have a foreign keyboard?  Try changing the keyboard layout to a keyboard that matches your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have a Swedish keyboard and a Swedish keyboard layout and this has not changed for several years. This is also not the problem, since as stated in the question, I can type or paste  backslash into some terminal-based programs (using Shift+Ctrl+V in Konsole).

Comment: But, it is very likely the problem because the issues you describe are almost always associated with foreign keyboards (and keyboard layouts).  An upgrade may have changed your layout, or the behavior of said layouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the programs you're using all use the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library to read input. So I guess you've misconfigured the readline library. The system configuration file is `/etc/inputrc` and the per-user file is `~/.inputrc`. You probably put one backslash too much in a binding, so that instead of binding a command to an escape sequence you've bound it to a sequence beginning with a backslash.

Right:  `"\e[1;5C": forward-word`  (escape sequence sent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>)
Wrong:  `"\\e[1;5C": forward-word`  (<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>)

If the problem was only in bash, the problematic binding would be in `~/.bashrc`. Note that in `.bashrc`, that binding above would be written `bind "\\e[1;5C: forward-word"`, with two backslashes because bash does a round of backslash expansion before passing the definition down to readline. (`bind '\e[1;5C: forward-word'` would also work, since backslashes lose their special meaning within single quotes.)

Comment: You were absolutely right! Thank you very much! I guessed so much
but I didn't know where to look.

(Although, as a detail, it seems I did have .inputrc exactly as what you 
term "Right", with only one initial backslash. Here it is:

    Tab: complete

    #Rebind some keys
    Ctrl-b: backward-word
    Ctrl-f: forward-word
    \e[1;5D : backward-word
    \e[1;5C : forward-word
    
    
However, as far as I am concerned, the problem is solved -- 
I don't need any of the last two bindings. After removing
them, logging out, loggin in everything worked.)

Comment: @Marcus: Comments can't have newlines, so your comments are hard to read. If you need further help, edit your question. (Also, please remove the first comment since the second one supersedes it.) But from what I see, you're missing the double quotes around the escape sequences. `"\e[1;5C"` makes `\e` stand for the escape character; without the double quotes, `\e[1;5c` has a backslash standing for itself.

Comment: Yes, I am new here, just trying to get the hang of the formatting (I have already without intention sent several half-baked comments). Also, you were right, the problem boiled down to missing double-quotes. I will look around as how to mark the problem as solved for the benefit of other owners of corrupt .inputrc

Comment: @Marcus: To mark the question as solved, click the check mark to the left of one of the answers (the one that helped you most). There's no point in putting the solution in your question: that's what the answers are for.